# Getting redirecting page issue for MS AD login using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am doing performance testing with JMeter for a cloud based application with Azure AD . I am not getting the expected response for below request:

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

Expected Response (By Fiddler ) = Sign in to your account having values for ctx, hpgrequestid, flowToken and canary
Actual Response (By Jmeter) = Redirecting (BssoInterrupt) page with no ctx and flowToken  values

I have done all correction for request POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf like wresult ( I am correlation whole xml) and wctx .apart from this in cookies i have correlated values ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN but still i am not getting expected response.

Where i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's due to missing or not properly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/)

I strongly doubt that your journey starts with [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request to the login page, my expectation is that you need to execute [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request first and extract dynamic parameters from the response.

Compare the requests which are being sent from JMeter and from the real browser, the requests must be exactly the same, any dynamic parameters are a subject to correlation. And don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

Comment: I am starting from the GET request https://login.microsoftonline.com/52384gsg2e435h444422/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&scope=openid+profile and capturing ORIGINAL_REQUEST and FLOW_TOKEN and passing them to 
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/GetCredentialType?mkt=en-US with userID and getting ESTS_REQUEST captured .

Comment: I am using HTTP Cookie Manager in my script. I have verified all response and requests from fiddler till request POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf only difference i found that in
jmeter below cookies are missing:

ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN 
ESTSAUTH
ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT
ESTSAUTHLIGHT

Comment: so i haved correlated and added ESTSWCTXFLOWTOKEN  this cookies value but others are not available in any response of any request .So my question is because of cookies i am getting redirecting response for requet
https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf or something else?